# Return last value query in MongoDB in Spring XD Source module

Tags: mongodb, spring-integration, spring-xd

I would like to be able to create a query/query-expression that I can use in SprinXD MongoDB Source module to return only the last document that has been inserted.

It seems that max-messages-per-poll doesn't do the trick ([paginated data with the help of mongo inbound adapter in spring integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26687359/paginated-data-with-the-help-of-mongo-inbound-adapter-in-spring-integration))

I know how to do it with agreggation, findOne(), limit(), etc, but I haven't found a way to do it with a query object.

My stream is the following:

```
mongodb --collectionName=Notifications --fixedRate=10000 --query={'$query':{}},{'$limit':1} | log
```

But I'm still returning all the documents.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't do that just with that simple MongoDB source. It requires only the JSON string in MongoDB query style, but there are no [hooks](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations-introduction/) to provide options like `limit`, `skip`, `sort` etc.

So, you must have a `transformer` processor module in your stream to filter all those undesired records from the `find` result.

Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) ticket against Spring Integration to improve `MongoDbMessageSource` to accept any `Query` object, not only `String` for simple `BasicQuery`.